# Integrating JSP with Apache SOLR

Tags: java, apache, jsp, solr, jsp-tags

Can someone help me with integrating JSP with Apache SOLR? I am new to Apache SOLR and havn't used JSP much in recent years but know the working of it. I have developed the UI in JSP and want to accept the user query from JSP and query them in Apache SOLR. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) What is your *specific* programming question?

Comment: I want to accept the values from JSP and use them to query Apache SOLR. That's what I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. You don't want to host your JSP in the same Jetty that Solr uses. Primarily because you don't want to expose your Solr server to the public internet (it is not secured). So, your JSP should be running on a separate server (Tomcat/Jetty/etc) and talk to Solr
2. To talk to Solr you probably will want to use SolrJ client, which you need to keep around in a global pool of some sort
3. Or, you could host your JSP views inside Spring container, in which case you could look at [Spring Data Solr](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) integration, which will manage the session for you.

Comment: Hello Alexandre, I tried using SolrJ to get the values from servlet  which retrieves from JSP but when I try using SolrJ functionalities like HttpSolrServer or SolrInputDocument, I get some error during the execution. Can you help me with that?  Also I ma testing my JSP and servlet code using Apache Tomcat which stops and gives some error during its execution while integrating with SolrJ.